# Кодировка html-файлов в Django на Visual Studio 2017

Tags: html, django, кодировка, visual-studio-2017

В проекте Django на Visual Studio 2017 контент-текст html-файлов работает только на латиннице. При смене на кириллицу - выдает ошибку кодировки. При этом, в файле settings.py кодировка установлена LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru', но в этой строке "-h1 charset="utf-8"-Requisites form:-/h1-" при смене "Реквизиты:", т.е. на кириллицу - выдает ошибку.. В чем тут дело и где ещё надо её настроить?

[image: [![Скрин ошибки:]

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: Ваши html-файлы сохранены явно не в кодировке utf-8

Comment: Да.. Уже разобрался, после сохранения в кодировке utf-8 всё заработало без замечаний! Чтобы сохранить файлы в нужной кодировке в Visual Studio 2017 необходимо в окне "сохранить как" выбрать её, нажав на стрелку возле кнопки "ОК".